# Google App Engine Datastore Overall Export File

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I use App Engine legacy bundled services and I use the datastore emulator. I wanted to import data from the live database. So according to instructions

```
curl -X POST localhost:8081/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]:import \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"input_url":"[ENTITY_EXPORT_FILES]"}'
```

I ran this (with the correct data in the []) and what I get as a response is

```
{
    "name": "projects/[project-name]/operations/7a9c8565eb4d403baf3bfa7edb7557f7",
    "metadata": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.datastore.admin.v1.ImportEntitiesMetadata",
        "common": {
            "startTime": "2023-05-08T07:30:33.844808Z",
            "endTime": "2023-05-08T07:30:36.638278Z",
            "operationType": "IMPORT_ENTITIES",
            "state": "SUCCESSFUL"
        },
        "entityFilter": {},
        "inputUrl": "/home/username/myexports/2023-05-03T13:17:23_41912/2023-05-03T13:17:23_41912.overall_export_metadata"
    },
    "done": true,
    "response": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Empty"
    }
}
```

It says that it's successful, but nothing is imported. I assume protobuf empty means it didn't find anything?

Comment: check the logs  to see if there are any errors or warnings it might be helpful to find the cause of the error.

Comment: So this is output of the import command, but maybe empty response means there was no error while importing? LIke if you would import GBs of data, would you like have all the data in response or what is your expectation? There's data viewer UI so you can check if the data are there or not: https://github.com/GabiAxel/google-cloud-gui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APPLICATION_ID was incorrect in the environment file. The function is actually very fast in doing the import.